# Why do the "Sum of Average Total Score" for some fields look odd?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I created a pivot table and then added 4 calculated fields. Then converted each of those calculated fields as average using the 'Number Format' Option. I am confused as I am getting really high values as average where my average should not exceed anything beyond 5.5.

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTFiY.png)

Comment: SUM of Average Total Score add all values, it's not Average, you should change the field from SUM to Average.

Comment: Yes, it not average, but it does become average when I add all those four columns and then divide them with 4, which is exactly what I did. Its not visible in the screen shot, but that's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

The calculated field always shows the sum of of all the fields, therefore, where ever there is only one instance of Burrito sold, the average will show up correctly and for those instances where there are more than one count for Burrito, due to the calculated field, the each instance will add up and then the average of that will be displayed.

I dragged Burrito into the values section as a 'Count of Burrito' and that clearly indicates why the some of the values have spiked up.

[Corrected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJBbY.png)

Comment: I don't know how to close this question myself, therefore if any of the super users can close this on my behalf.